# Is using Javascript in odoo.fields.HTML possible?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

I want to integrate Adobe Captivate Content (Export: index.html, along with src-folder) into ODOO Community Edition v13 e-Learning Module (website_slides).

The [slide.slide](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_slides/models/slide_slide.py) model already offers slide_type 'webpage' alongside the field 'html_content'.
The field 'html_content' is of type odoo.fields.HTML. To get the requirement stated above to work, I need to embed Javascript in the given html_content. It seems like the JS-scripts are not working. I also tried with a simple [Hello World](https://javascript.info/hello-world) script.

Can someone help?

Best regards,
Lars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution already.

Looking at [odoo/fields.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/fields.py) -> class Html, you can see that by default the given value is being sanitized using [odoo/tools/mail.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/tools/mail.py) -> html_sanitize(), which removes the HTML-Elements in 'tags_to_kill'. 'tags_to_kill' also contains "script".

After overriding html_content in [slide.slide](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_slides/models/slide_slide.py) with the following, the Javascript-code is being executed:

```py
html_content = fields.Html(
   sanitize=False,
   sanitize_tags=False,
   sanitize_attributes=False)
```